# How to check if website is authorized by user on access his information in FaceBook Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I am working on the FaceBook Javascript API.
I want to know if there is any way in which we can find out if a user has authorized a web site or not.

Answer (score 0):

if authorized, the `signed_request` attribute from facebook will have a `user_id` in it (after decoding it with the website's `oauth_secret` )